# partial inverses of x tanh(log(1 + e^x))

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, inverse-function

$f(x) = x \tanh(\log(1 + e^x))$ is not one-to-one. It has a minima at $x=-1.19243$.

We can divide the domain of the function into two sets: $\mathbf{A} = \{x|x \lt -1.19243...\}$ and $\mathbf{B} = \mathbb{R} - A$. How can one find the partial inverses for the two domains?

Comment: Are you trying to build a neural net? Also, why do you expect there to be a nice partial inverse, and in what context do you need it?

Comment: Do you mean an inverse function?

Comment: @BenjaminWang It's memory efficient implementation of gradients in a neural network. I am trying to store one bit (side) and the activation output (already stored) in the forward pass. Just trading performance for memory. I want to get $x$ from $y$ and that one bit to compute the gradient.

Comment: @Allawonder Yes.

Comment: @Yashas If so, I don't think such exists in closed form in terms of elementary functions.  The problem is the factor $x.$

Comment: @Yashas by the way why do you need to take tanh of a softmax? Why not use sigmoid? See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/irwtuza5xi

Comment: @BenjaminWang I don't have control over the choice of function. The function in the OP is called the mish activation. There are models that are already trained with it. Changing the function will degrade the accuracy or the model has to be retrained. I need to get what others have used run fast with a low memory footprint.

Comment: @Yashas Understood. Just saw the paper